# How can I increase the number of bins for my plot using pandas / geopandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

Currently a lot of my data is showing with a huge range of values in one bin - all data goes from 0 to 1.31, but my top bin colour is holding 0.15 to 1.31.

This is my code to plot:

```
merged.plot(column='vaccinations_per_person', scheme="quantiles", figsize=(25, 20),
           legend=True, norm=colour, cmap='Oranges', missing_kwds = 
           dict(color = "lightgrey", label = "No Data"))
plt.title('Vaccinations per Person',fontsize=25)
```

And this is my legend:

[image: screen-grab of my legend]

Comment: Please create a [reprex] including sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily by specifying the number of bins as `k=10` (if you want 10).

```
 merged.plot(column='vaccinations_per_person', scheme="quantiles", figsize=(25, 20),
           legend=True, norm=colour, cmap='Oranges', missing_kwds = 
           dict(color = "lightgrey", label = "No Data"), k=10)
```

Comment: this has helped in gaining more bins but the top bin is now 0.19 - 1.31 which hasn't solved my issue

Comment: In that case, you need a different classification scheme than `quantiles`, one which better reflects your distribution. GeoPandas supports a wide range of them, one should fit your needs. All those implemented in mapclassify are available, check them in the docs: https://pysal.org/mapclassify/api.html

Answer (score -1):

- use a colormap with scatter and there is no limit to bins

```
import pandas as pd
import io, requests, matplotlib

dfraw = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/vaccinations/vaccinations.csv").text))

cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["aqua","limegreen","green"])

dfraw["date"] = pd.to_datetime(dfraw["date"])
dfp = (dfraw.sort_values(["iso_code","date"])
 .groupby(["iso_code"], as_index=False).last()
 .loc[:,["iso_code","people_vaccinated_per_hundred"]]
 .dropna()
 .plot(kind="scatter", x="iso_code", y="people_vaccinated_per_hundred", c="people_vaccinated_per_hundred", cmap=cmap)
)
```

[image]

Using `geopandas` and `folium` with the same colormap and a bit more preparation you get to:
[image]

Comment: This does not allow custom classification schemes based on `mapclassify` (as `quantiles`) OP has in their code.

Comment: fair enough - however question was extended to geopandas not just matplotlib.  From working with COVID vaccination data I have found bins to not be useful,  better to treat data as a continuous series rather than making it discrete

Comment: That very much depends on the distribution of your data and cannot be generalised.

Comment: as I said wrt to COVID vaccination data - very much better to consider as continuous.  Otherwise you miss how well countries like Bhutan are doing...  I've done the homework on this data set